# How can I retrieve the price on airbnb using beautifulsoup to scrape?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape airbnb's listings by city (for the 5 cities listed in the code) and would like to gather information such as: price, a link to the listing, room type, # of guests, etc.

I was able to get the link, but I'm having trouble getting the price.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
from urllib.parse import urljoin  # For joining next page url with base url
from datetime import datetime  # For inserting the current date and time

start_url_nyc = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/New-York--NY--United-States"
start_url_mia = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/Miami--FL--United-States"
start_url_la = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/Los_Angeles--CA--United-States"
start_url_sf = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/San_Francisco--CA--United-States"
start_url_orl = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/Orlando--FL--United-States"


def scrape_airbnb(url):
    # Set up the URL Request
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

   # Iterate over search results
   for search_result in soup.find_all('div', 'infoContainer_tfq3vd'):
            # Parse the name and price and record the time
        link_end = search_result.find('a').get('href')
        link = "https://www.airbnb.com" + link_end
        price = search_result.find('span', 'data-pricerate').find('data-reactid').get(int)
   return (price)

print(scrape_airbnb(start_url_orl))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the html code:

```
<span data-pricerate="true" data-reactid=".91165im9kw.0.2.0.3.2.1.0.$0.$grid_0.$0/=1$=01$16085565.$=1$16085565.0.2.0.1.0.0.0.1:1">552</span>
```

This is your code

```
price = search_result.find('span', 'data-pricerate').find('data-reactid').get(int)
```

first:

> Some attributes, like the data-* attributes in HTML 5, have names that can’t be used as the names of keyword arguments:

```
data_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>')
data_soup.find_all(data-foo="value")
# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

> You can use these attributes in searches by putting them into a
>   dictionary and passing the dictionary into find_all() as the attrs
>   argument:

```
data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"})
# [<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>]
```

than:

```
price = search_result.find('span', attrs={"data-pricerate":"true"})
```

this will return a span tag which contains price as string, just use `.text`

```
price = search_result.find('span', attrs={"data-pricerate":"true"}).text
```